# There is 25% Rob will wear blue shirt, 60% he will have dinner with his girl. the probability he wear a shirt but not having dinner

Tags: probability

Event $A$ is that Rob will wear a blue shirt. Event $B$ is that Rob will have dinner with his girlfriend. What is $P(A \cap B')$?

$P(A)$=$0.25$, $P(B)$=$0.6$

The events are independent.

Please help, thanks!!!

(I have now realised that the answer is 0.25 $\times$ 0.4)

Comment: 0.25*0.4? is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. But you should fix your question rather than adding it in a comment!

Comment: Be careful how you write things though.  Probability he will "wear **a shirt**" but not having dinner, or probability he will "wear a **blue** shirt" but not have dinner.  If the question was indeed about wearing *any* color shirt, then there is not enough information to answer.

Comment: @JMoravitz has a point.

Comment: yeah thanks guys I forgot adding the word "blue"

Comment: When events are independent,

$P(A)P(B)$ = $P(A \cap B)$

From your question, we know that $P(A)=0.25$ and $P(B)=0.6$.

We want to find the probability that Rob wears a blue shirt and does not have dinner with his girlfriend.

Since $P(B)$ expresses the probability that he will have dinner with his girlfriend, $1-P(B)$ expresses the probability that he will not have dinner with his girlfriend.

$P(A \cap B ' )$ = $P(A)P(B')$ = $(0.25)(0.4)$

Answer (score 4):

Since they are independent events, you can compute the following probability-space:

```
 Wear a blue shirt | Have dinner with his girlfriend | Probability
-------------------|---------------------------------|--------------------
 No                | No                              | (1-0.25) * (1-0.6)
-------------------|---------------------------------|--------------------
 No                | Yes                             | (1-0.25) * 0.6
-------------------|---------------------------------|--------------------
 Yes               | No                              | 0.25 * (1-0.6)
-------------------|---------------------------------|--------------------
 Yes               | Yes                             | 0.25 * 0.6
```

The answer to your question is the third row in the table above.

Comment: @Shwoo: You're welcome. Feel free to accept the answer by clicking on the V next to it :)

Answer (score 0):

For wearing a shirt, it's 25% since it can be blue from any color.  Not having dinner is a complement of the 60%, so it's 25% times 40% since it's two events together.  This is the same as a quarter of 40%, so it's a 10% chance that he will wear a shirt but not have dinner with his girl if he has only blue shirts.

Comment: yeah thats what I thought, thanks a lot!!

Comment: You know, you could've had information about the color of the shirt, but whatever.